# How get string outside for Loop

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist

Good Day to all
I have ArrayList with 10 string TITLE  inside for loop it works fine But outside loop is just shown only one string last title. Now inside for loop in show all 10 string but outside it just show last one.

```
        titles = new ArrayList<String>();

        String title = null;
        for (int i=0 ;i< titles.size();i++){
            title = titles.get(i);
            Log.d("zxc",""+title);
        }

        Log.d("asd",""+title);
```

Comment: to access all elements you should use a toString() method for array.

Comment: What are you really asking?

Comment: `outside it just show last one` ... **of course**! Outside your loop you are only printing the variable `title`, which you have set to the **last item** of your ArrayList, in the last iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 1):

To show all the strings of your arraylist you can use `titles.toString()`.

For example

```
Log.d("asd",titles.toString())
```